# Connection Refused error after upgrading EKS from 1.23 to 1.24

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, infrastructure

Hello I have a problem after the after the upgrade from 1.23 to 1.24

The error I receive is the following

```
plugin type="aws-cni" name="aws-cni" failed (add): add cmd: Error received from AddNetwork gRPC call: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:50051: connect: connection refused"
```

after updating the cluster the nodes have all been replaced and are all version v1.24.13 i have also updated the components

```
coredns:v1.9.3-eksbuild.3 kube-proxy:v1.24.10-eksbuild.2 image: amazon-k8s-cni:v1.12.6 amazon-k8s-cni-init:v1.12.6
```

Any suggestions? Do I have to change the code of the application to solve it?

thank you!